# Behavior of extension.onConnect, extension.connect and Port

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am curious how onConnect, connect, and port.postMessage/onMessage are supposed to behave if there are multiple listeners.  The documentation is unclear what happens, and where disconnect comes in.

Say I have three contexts (background page, content script, and a browser action popup) - each on startup has registered an onConnect listener.  The background page wants to send a message to both of them - can I simply connect(), then send a message via the Port?  What if I want receipt confirmation?  Can I say - port.postMessage({ received: true }) in both of the contexts that received the onConnect?  Will I receive two messages in the guy who connect()ed?  Will I receive an onConnect() message in the background page where I called the connect()?

I've read http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html and http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html# - they make it pretty clear how sendRequest and onRequest work, but I need delivery confirmation, which I don't think I can adequately get out of sendRequest.

My question boils down to:  how many "ends" can there be for a Port object, and how does it handle "disconnect" calls from any of the ends?

Answer (score 1):

The ports are actually pretty simple. I think an example will work better, mind you I'm not using a content script, but here is a utility script I build called socket.js that allows continuous 2 way communication between a popup and background page.

https://github.com/jjNford/chrome-extension-socket

I am currently using it in this extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jgekomkdphbcbfpnfjgcmjnnhfikinmn

The postTask API is nice for UX purposes. I know I didn't directly answer your question but I hope this helps you.

Comment: I like examples - but what I don't understand about ports is whether they always only have two ends or if they can do communication between many different parts of the application.

Comment: The API describes ports a way to create "listeners", knowing the way Google usually does things I would assume it can have more than one end (distinguished by port.name).  The best way to figure this out would be to test it.  My GitHub Repo provides an example... just add what is missing.